# Implicitly check return type of subclass in Python

Tags: python, class, subclass, metaclass

I need to check the return type of all methods of any subclass that extends my base class. I know how to check for the parent class (suppose I want the return to be a dictionary):

```py
# decorator for class methods
def check_is_dict(fun):
    def check_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ret = fun(*args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(ret, dict):  # check the return type
            raise TypeError("Wrong return type")
        return ret
    return check_wrapper


class ParentClass:
    @check_is_dict
    def foo(self):
        return {str(i): i for i in range(10)}  # dummy dict

    @check_is_dict
    def bar(self):
        return {str(i): i for i in range(10)}  # dummy dict
```

But I would need a way to implicitly check the return type of the child class, for example defining:

```py
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def my_method(self):
        return [i for i in range(10)]  # dummy list
```

I want the call to `ChildClass().my_method()` to fail because of the wrong return type. I think using metaclasses is the right way to go but I don't know how to proceed.

The final goal is to have the return type checked for any method of any subclass without having to decorate the subclass methods directly.

Thanks a lot to everyone. Have a mice day :)

Comment: indeed  - the second, metaclass user, answer on the question marked as duplicate seems to do exactly what you need.

Comment: @jsbueno thanks a lot, I came to a similar solution